# inline edit with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using inline editing using jQuery. I can edit the table data easily when the data is not big (less than 100 rows) But when it is more than 100 rows the page will be slower in loading and the edit function will be very slow(slow to open the edit box).

I found that the problem is from this import:
`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>`

If I remove this line the page will be loaded fast as normal. Any suggestions please.

Thanks,

Comment: load your JS files in the footer & use a local copy of jQuery library instead of online version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a local copy of the jquery and a higher version preferably over 1.7. Put all your js code  at the bottom of the page.

```
<body>
<!--  document body here -->
<script src="js/jquery1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<!--  some jquery plugins here -->
<script>
 // your code here.
</script>
</body>
```

And you can use a [jquery plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) to edit things in place. If you are facing issues with your custom code.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to manage pagination for listing of the records rather than listing all records. And always include js in the footter